# Trouble Defining a Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to define a class in JavaScript. I found this link (http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) but it doesn't seem to meet my needs. Essentially, I want to have a class that has properties and functions. When a class is initialized, I want to automatically call the init function. At this time, when I create a new Item using the following code, I get an error:

var item = new Item();

*The error says: Object has no method 'init'.*

My class definition looks like the following:

```
function Item() {
    this.id = null;
    this.name = "";
    this.description = "";

    this.init();
    this.init = function () {
        this.id = "54321";
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I create a constructor in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are instantiating the Item class, you could use the prototype of Item to take some of the logic out of the constructor. In the example below, Item is instantiated with all default properties from the prototype (including the init function)

```
function Item() {
  this.init();
}

Item.prototype = {
  id: null,
  name: '',
  description: '',
  init: function () {
    this.id = "54321";
  }
};
```

There are many ways to manipulate the prototype - here it is set to an Object to set all properties at once, but it could have had each item added individually by using `Item.prototype.someVariable = something` style syntax.

One note on setting the prototype - any non-primitive data type (ie: not boolean, number or string) will be shared across all instances (useful for sharing functions like the init function) whereas primitives will be per instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't boolean, number, and strings primitive types? Maybe i'm ready it wrong. Either way, how do I create instance specific Arrays?

Comment: That's right - I was saying non-primitive which is _not_ boolean number and strings... If you need arrays or objects on a per-instance basis, create them in the constructor or as part of another function on the prototype, eg `function Item() { this.obj = {}; }`

Answer (score 10):

You're calling `init()` before you've defined it. Simply move the invocation below the definition:

```
function Item() {
    this.id = null;
    this.name = "";
    this.description = "";

    this.init = function () {
        this.id = "54321";
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Comment: Still that's the wrong way of defining classes in Javascript. Everytime you make a new instance, the engine recreates all of the methods instead of just passing a new 'this' to them; You'd better use prototypes and the main function as constructor

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `init` method before it's defined. Only `FunctionDeclaration`s in JavaScript are hoisted. Not `FunctionExpression`s assigned to a variable. Remember, only declarations are hoisted. Not definitions.